# Difference between using global variable and pointer variable?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I have been coding a binary tree problem of finding maximum between ancestor and a node.I have coded it in two ways.But it provides two different answers.How?

```
int res=INT_MIN;

int maxDiff(Node* root){
 if(root==NULL){
    return INT_MAX;
 }else if(root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL){
    return root->data;  
 }else{
    int mini = min(maxDiff(root->left),maxDiff(root->right));
    res = max(res,root->data-mini);
    return min(mini,root->data);
 }  
}

Print(res); //Printing ans
```

Another is....

```
int helpmaxDiff(Node* root,int *res){
 if(root==NULL){
    return INT_MAX;
 }else if(root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL){
    return root->data;  
 }else{
    int mini = min(helpmaxDiff(root->left,res),helpmaxDiff(root->right,res));
    *res = max(*res,(root->data)-mini);
    return min(mini,root->data);
 }  
}

int maxDiff(Node* root)
{
 int res=INT_MIN;
 // Your code here 
 helpmaxDiff(root,&res);
 print(res); //printing res
}
```

https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/maximum-difference-between-node-and-its-ancestor/1 
 This is the problem I was coding .
 I found that the function which has res as global variable fails and the function which has res as pointer variable (also as parameter) runs well.

Comment: Please elaborate on `problem of finding maximum between ancestor and a node`. Ancestor could be immediate parent or parent of parent etc. In other words describe the problem clearly, concisely that the code is written for.

Comment: For which input you found the result was different?

Comment: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/maximum-difference-between-node-and-its-ancestor/1 <br> This is the problem I was coding <br> I found that the function which has res as global variable fails and the function which has res as pointer variable (also as parameter) runs well.

Comment: Can you tell us for which test case you found the results were different?

Comment: while submitting the code in the problem link provided,it failed